# Using generic func signature

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I would like to implement a simple (testing purposes only) in memory repository as below. The interfaces it implements are generic. One of the methods "Delete" is used in the sample code below.

The cast of predicate throws an exception. How can I implement the deleted method correctly?

```
public class InMemoryReportingRepository : IReportingRepository
{
    private readonly List<IDto> m_dtos;

    public InMemoryReportingRepository()
    {
        m_dtos = new List<IDto>();
    }

    // ommitted stuff

    public void Delete<TEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate) where TEntity : class, IDto
    {
        var delete = m_dtos.FirstOrDefault((Func<IDto, bool>) predicate.Compile());

        m_dtos.Remove(delete);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `public void Delete(Expression<Func<IDto, bool>> predicate)`?

Comment: My interfaces are like this below, that is the reason...
    public interface IUpdateModel
    {
        void Save<T>(T dto) where T : class, IDto;
        void Update<T>(T entity) where T : class, IDto;
        void Delete<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) where T : class, IDto;
        void Delete<T>(T entity) where T : class, IDto;
    }

    public interface IUpdateModel<T> where T : IDto
    {
        void Save(T dto);
        void Update(T entity);
        void Delete(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
        void Delete(T entity);
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
public void Delete<TEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate) where TEntity : class, IDto
{
    var compiled = predicate.Compile();
    var toDelete = m_dtos.FirstOrDefault(dto => (dto is TEntity) && compiled((TEntity)dto));
    m_dtos.Remove(delete);
}
```

`Func<TEntity, bool>` and `Func<IDto, bool>` are completely different types, which is why your cast failed.

However, I would recommend using class level generics for your in memory data store:

```
public class DataStore<TEntity> : IDataStore<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IDto
{
  private readonly List<TEntity> m_dtos = new List<TEntity>();
  ...
  public void Delete(Func<TEntity, bool> predicate)
  {
    var toDelete = m_dtos.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
    m_dtos.Remove(toDelete);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rich, it works. You are correct in your second suggestion. In fact, I already have the class level generics implementation. I wanted to use the method level generics version of simple ctor injection to classes which depends on this repository. This is only for testing purposes so your implementation will work beautifully.

Comment: What's an `IEntity`? Didn't you mean `TEntity`?

Comment: It is TEntity, he has a typo.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Delete<TEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate) where TEntity : class, IDto
```

Takes an expression typed on a predicate that takes a `TEntity` where `TEntity` is a reference type that implements `IDto`

```
(Func<IDto, bool>) predicate.Compile();
```

Casts the expression's predicate to `Func<IDto, bool>`, which is not what it is.

There's a few variants on just what you want here, but I suspect that:

```
public void Delete<TEntity>(Expression<Func<IDto, bool>> predicate) where TEntity : class, IDto
```

Will give you what you need.